# Howto assign HTML semantics to my XML elements to get them rendered in my web browser?

Tags: css, xml, dtd

I have an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<todo>
    <list><item>first</item><item>second</item></list>
    <list><item>first</item><item>second</item></list>
</todo>
```

Now I want to view the file in a browser. I want to have the `<list>` element rendered like a `<ul>` html-element, the `<item>` elements like `<li>` html-elements. i know that I can use xslt to transform the xml into an html document. but: is there a way to directly assign the html semantics to the elements of my list, e.g. with css (something like `list{display:ul}`) or a dtd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

See [W3C-Website Style Sheets with XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/).

You can use CSS to declare for each XML element how the browser should display it. But you have to be more verbose than in HTML, because for plain XML there are no predefined styles.

In the XML header add a reference to your CSS file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="todo.css"?>
<todo>
   <list><item>first</item><item>second</item></list>
   <list><item>first</item><item>second</item></list>
</todo>
```

Here is an example CSS file (todo.css):

```
todo {
  display: block;
}

list {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 5mm;
  margin-top: 1cm;
}

item {
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: circle;
}
```

For each element you can define the `display` style (`block`, `inline`, `none`, `list-item`).

For `display: list-item` you can additionally use the styles

- `list-style-image: url(bullet.gif)` to decalare a bullet icon graphic
- `list-style-image` with values `inside` or `outside`
- `list-style-type` with  values `circle`, `disc`, `square`, `none`

Comment: this is what I hoped to be possible. are there also display styles for form elements like <select> or <input>? or for <table>?

Comment: Look here for a list of all possible `display` values: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp There are options for a table but it seems that it isn't possible to render form elements. For that purpose it might be better to use something like XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

No, XML is not HTML. If you want to display your XML as HTML, you will need to transform it using XSLT.

Comment: but there is xhtml. how do they get their stuff rendered without transforming it? is xhtml a special case, hard-coded into the browsers?

Comment: Yes. (BTW you can apply styling to arbitrary XML, but there's no way of giving it HTML semantics.)

Comment: XHTML is HTML that follows the stricter rules of XML formatting. That, of course, is a very generic explanation; It is much more complex than that.

Comment: just to be sure that i understand. when the browser parses my xml and recognizes an element from the xhtml-namespace (http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml, e.g. ul), it does something special with it (rendering it as a list), that I could not enable for the elements of my own namespace. Right?

Comment: Creating your own DTD or namespace is just going to allow you to specify what content will be encapsulated by custom tags. Example: `<!ELEMENT MYTAG (#PCDATA)>`. It will **not** change how the browser renders it. Browsers display XML as XML and HTML as HTML. If you want it to display as HTML, it needs to be delivered to the browser in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display XML as HTML. Use some transformation utilite (XSLT).